# Pass CSV String from Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, csv, dhtmlx

I'm trying to export my DHTMLX Grid to a CSV file. I have the framework for it set up, but am running in an issue where if I try to export more than ~25 rows, it fails. No error message or anything. Below is my code:

Javascript

```
myGrid.csvParser = myGrid.csvExtParser;
myGrid.setCSVDelimiter('|');
myGrid.csv.row = "endOfRow";

var gridCsvData = myGrid.serializeToCSV();

$.post("data/export.php?csvdata="+gridCsvData);
```

PHP

```
$csvData = $_REQUEST['csvdata'];

$csv = explode('endOfRow',$csvData);

$myfile = "grid.csv";

$fh = fopen($myfile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

foreach($csv as $line) {
   fputcsv($fh, explode('|',$line),',','"');
}

fclose($fh);


//Redirect output to a client's web browser (csv)
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=grid.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

readfile('grid.csv');
```

Any help is appreciated. I assume it's some kind of size limit problem on the POST and I've tried modifying the limit to 20MB in the .htaccess file. As I said, this works perfectly with only a few rows (<25), but once I try to export any more than that it never generates the .csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `$.post` (from jQuery right?) doesn't handle such a huge url. You should add a parameter that can be handle as parameter of the HTTP POST query:

```
$.post(
  "data/export.php", 
  { 
    csvdata: gridCsvData
  }
);
```

Comment: Works great thanks man..still having trouble getting it to prompt the user to save the file. Any idea on why that wouldn't be popping up? It is saving on the server just not prompting.

Comment: Have you tried with `application/csv` instead of `text/csv` in the `Content-type` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've gone back and forth between those two. No difference that I could see

Comment: It might depend on the browser too. You might have a look at these questions/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+force+download